# How to JSON.Encode a Set with Elm?

Tags: json, encode, elm

I am trying to `JSON.Encode` a `Set String` into a JSON list.

```
Encode.list <| Set.map Encode.string mySet
```

How should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to think of doing this with a pipe instead, as that can be more readable

```
mySet
    |> Set.map Encode.string 
    |> Set.toList
    |> Encode.list
```

Answer (score 4):

Thank to the help I got from the Elm community on slack, I found a way to do it:

`Encode.list <| List.map Encode.string <| Set.toList mySet`